# Sending e-mail with ASP.NET MVC3 with attachment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, itext

I searched everywhere, but without finding any solution.
The problem is: I'm trying to send e-mails with attachments from an ASP.NET MVC3 application. The problem is: the attachment is (or should be) a pdf file created with iTextSharp. I already have a method in a Controller that returns an ActionResult, and this method produces a pdf response. The problem is: how can I get teh file from this ActionResult?

Comment: this is not specific to MVC. wrap the pdf generation code in a method and use that to get the attachment. There are a lot of example to send emails in C#

Comment: Maybe this is the better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your code which generates the PDF fike stream to a method which you can **Re Use** in many places and use that when creating the attachment

```
public Byte[] GetGeneratedPDF(string someParameter)
{
   //Do your magic to create the PDF and return the byte array

}
```

Now you can call this method to create the Attachement

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(GetGeneratedPDF("hi"));
Attachment att1= new Attachment(stream, "stack123.pdf");
msg.Attachments.Add(att1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take the same logic that you use inside your "PDF generation action method" and add the `Stream` (or whatever iTextSharp returns) as an attatchment to your mail:

```
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream, "name", "mimeType"));
```

Comment: I am trying this solution, but "extracting" a stream from an ActionResult object seems to be not possible.

Comment: No, not from the ActionResult but from the PDF generator. Have a look at Shyju's answer, this should make it clear.